# Check if time difference is less than 45 mins and if time is past current time - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an easy thing to do in PHP with code like this;

```
if (strtotime($given_time) >= time()+300) echo "You are online";
```

But can't find anything on SO to do exactly this in javascript.
I want to check if the difference between a given time and the current time is less than 45mins

For instance

```
$scope.given_time = "14:10:00"
$scope.current_time = new Date();
```

I'm only concerned with the time part. I need to extract time part from `new Date();` and then compare.

Then this should be `true`

How can I achieve this with Javascript:

```
if ($scope.given_time - $scope.current_time < 45 minutes && if $scope.given_time > time()) {
   // do something
}
```

The below function provided by @Pete solves the first part (45mins part)

```
function checkTime(time) {
  var date = new Date();
  var date1 = new Date((date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + time);

  var minutes = (date1.getTime() - date.getTime()) / (60 * 1000);

  if (minutes > 45 || (minutes < 0 && minutes > -1395)) { 
  // greater than 45 is todays time is above 45 minutes
  // less than 0 means the next available time will be tomorrow and the greater than -1395 means it will be more than 45 minutes from now into tomorrow

    document.write(time + ': true<br />');
  } else {
    document.write(time + ': false<br />');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtracting two date objects results in difference in milliseconds. So compare that to the number of milliseconds in 45 minutes.

```js
var date1 = new Date();
var date2 = new Date();
date2.setTime(date2.getTime() + (50 * 60 * 1000));  //adding 50 minutes just to see console message
    
if (date2-date1 >= 45*60*1000) {
    console.log("greater than 45 minutes");
}
```

Comment: Does this put in to account date? if the time falls into tomorrow?

Comment: Yes because calling `new Date` creates date data for the given date as well as time.

Answer (score 1):

compare it with timestamps. IMO this is the easiest way. I don't know what this has to do with angularJs.

```
var currentTimeStamp = new Date().getTime(); //timestamp in ms
var beforeTimeStamp = startDate.getTime(); //timestamp in ms

if (currentTimeStamp - beforeTimeStamp < 45*60*1000 && currentTimeStamp - beforeTimeStamp > 0) {
  //do smth
}
```

note that `startDate` is the Date which was created by logging in for example.

Comment: This doesn't answer the whole question

Comment: because the topic poster modified his question afterwards